# Factor boy same model property instance on parent and related factory

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am sharing my solution to my own problem to which I realised the solution while typing the question... it may be useful to others.

In my Django models I have a `Gateway` that has a set of `Node`s with and they both should have the same `Vendor`.

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False)

class Gateway(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, related_name='gateways')

class Node(models.Model):
    gateway = models.ForeignKey(Gateway, related_name='nodes')
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, related_name='nodes')
```

Now I would like to generate fake data with `factory boy`. Here the `VendorFactory` and `NodeFactory`.

```
class VendorFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor

    name = 'test_vendor'


class NodeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Node

    # is created after this node instance
    vendor = factory.SubFactory(VendorFactory)
```

That works fine when creating the `node = NodeFactory()`.

The problem is with the `GatewayFactory`. What I would like is that `gateway = GatewayFactory()` creates a `Gateway` that is referenced by a `Node` instance and both the Gateway and the Node using the same `Vendor`.

A tried a few things but failed. Here one shot:

```
class GatewayFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Gateway

    node = factory.RelatedFactory(NodeFactory, 'gateway', vendor=factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.vendor))
    vendor = factory.SubFactory(VendorFactory)
```

The problem is that the `RelatedFactory` is evaluated after the GatewayFactory and a `LazyAttribute` or a `SelfAttribute` are evaluated in the context of the NodeFactory.

Answer (score 2):

> The solution is in the fact that "the RelatedFactory is evaluated after the GatewayFactory and a LazyAttribute or a SelfAttribute are **evaluated in the context of** the NodeFactory"

Thus, we can reference the parent to get the vendor attribute:

```
class GatewayFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Gateway

    node = factory.RelatedFactory(NodeFactory, 'gateway', vendor=factory.SelfAttribute('gateway.vendor'))
    vendor = factory.SubFactory(VendorFactory)
```

This works for the `LazyAttribute` as well:

```
class GatewayFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Gateway

    node = factory.RelatedFactory(NodeFactory, 'gateway', vendor=factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.gateway.vendor))
    vendor = factory.SubFactory(VendorFactory)
```